# Do arrow functions not bind `this` inside ES6 classes?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm surprised this doesn't work. (I'm running `iojs` 2.3.0 with the `--harmony_arrow_functions` flag.)

```
class Foo {
  constructor() { this.foo = "foo"; }
  sayHi() { return (() => this.foo)(); }
}
f = new Foo();
f.sayHi // Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined.
```

I would have expected the arrow function to pick up the right value for `this`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the problem, but my version works fine for me:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "foo";
    }

    sayHi() {
        return (() => console.log(this.foo))();
    }
}

const f = new Foo();
f.sayHi();
```

BTW: I am using `babel`

Comment: Cool, so I guess it must just be an iojs/V8 bug.

Comment: Glad I found this question, because I ran into the same issue weeks ago. It took me a while to find out that it is a V8 issue. Because, indeed, with babel it works. Now I can sleep peacefully again.

Answer (score 0):

Your IIFE is creating a new scope. `this` is then referring to the scope of the IIFE where `this.foo` is undefined.

The way you'd get around this is by binding your IIFE.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = 'foo';
    }
    sayHi() {
        return (() => {
            return this.foo;
        }.bind(this))();
    }
}

let f = new Foo();
console.log(f.sayHi()); //foo
```

Comment: But is that the expected behavior? My understanding was that arrow functions were supposed to inherit their value of `this` from the surrounding lexical context.

Comment: Apparently not. We had a discussion in the [JS chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23916739#23916739) and apparently the arrow functions in V8 are broken.

Comment: I don't see an IIFE in the OP's code (if you mean that the arrow function is immediately executed, that's irrelevant)

Comment: @FelixKling do you know what IIFE stands for?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Yes.