# Back to previous "this"

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I get "back to previous `this`? To explain better, I created this sample code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(x,y,z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.z = z;
        }, 1000);
    }
}

var myVariable = new MyClass(10,15,20);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(myVariable.z);
}, 1500);
```

The problem is that last lane should output `20` but instead it gives me an error.

I understand why though. The `this.z` was understood as `this` of `setTimeout()`, not `myClass`, making `myVariable.z` as undefined.

How can I set `this` of `myVariable` inside my `MyClass`?

Comment: Save it into some variable outside block

Comment: Do something like `var that = this` in whatever context you want to save the `this` of.

Comment: Use an arrow function within setTimeout() or do the classic `var me = this;` and use `me` within setTimeout().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ES6 arrow function with lexical binding of `this`:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(x,y,z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.z = z;
        }, 1000);
    }
}

var myVariable = new MyClass(10,15,20);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(myVariable.z);
}, 1500);
```

Using `this` within an arrow function refers to the `this` of the surrounding code block (also called static scope).

See also: [Do arrow functions not bind `this` inside ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868265/do-arrow-functions-not-bind-this-inside-es6-classes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: My app is Chromium-based, so this solution is perfect. Thanks a lot! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function (closure) gets called asynchronously, so it does not run in object context.
You may however save the reference in the upper context and use it in the closure.

e.g. `var that = this;` then `that.z = z;`

Comment: Alternatively you could use "fat arrow" syntax. `setTimeout( () => {
            this.z = z;
        }, 1000);`

Comment: That requires ES6 and as such it won't work in browsers like iOS 9 and below, or IE 11 and below.